# What is the formula for vapor pressure of liquid related to surface tension of liquid?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

What is the formula for vapor pressure of liquid related to surface tension of liquid? I know that if the surface tension increases, vapor pressure will decrease. Toluene evaporates faster than ethanol even though it is having more surface tension. How can I relate vapor pressure and surface tension between every solvent through a formula?

Comment: Who said there is a formula?

Comment: Please make sure to write your arguments coherently so we can follow them. Are you using the example of toluene vs ethanol as a counterargument to what your intuition tells you? Also, cite sources if possible.